# Is Jun openly homosexual?

Tags: persona

In *Shin Megami Tensei Persona 2 - Innocent Sin*, after I beat Lisa's Shadow in the Taurus Temple and selected *"I'm glad you feel that way"*, everyone is commenting on Tatsuya's own confession.

After that Lisa comments on not losing to an older woman and mopey boy. This to me seems like Lisa is saying that she won't lose to Maya or Jun in claiming Tatsuya.

Now I have always got the impression Jun is effeminate or something of the like but I never got an impression that he was homosexual. I am wondering then if Jun is homosexual. If not, what is Lisa talking about?

Comment: I'm thinking this should be in Arqade because Persona 2 did not have an anime or manga.

Comment: @AnimatedLime however it's accepted to ask questions about Japanese games so long as it's plot related not gameplay related [related meta](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/418/1587)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I honestly don't know how much you were paying attention to the game if you didn't figure out Jun is homosexual... He has loved Tatsuya since he was a child; this game is one of few that do not shy away from exposing his orientation.

If you look at the demon contact description he has with Lisa, it says they are rivals in love (over Tatsuya). In his demon contact descriptions with Maya and Tatsuya as well as Lisa and Tatsuya, both are referred to as "love triangles" because he is after Tatsuya as well. He even flirts with Tatsuya, very obviously, and both Eikichi and Lisa acknowledge this. In fact it wouldn't be at all outrageous to suggest Tatsuya returns his affections, given his behaviour in-game and the word of the creators. In any case, Jun is homosexual and Tatsuya is bisexual, they are both explicitly attracted to men.